# Best way get the data for paging concept in web applications in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Can anybody explain the which is best way writing code in my scenario

I have data base with some tables, I have to show data from the database in pages (contains 20 rows in each page)

I am doing my app is - I am retrieving the data from data by 20 rows each and every time for showing in a each page using SP, every page click I connected to the database and showing data in to front end page.

My idea is - to get complete data in to datatable in one single query execution (single iteration) and store the data in session and use it in every page click.

Is this way is correct or not?

And which is best way to get the data of every page click .

Comment: Horrible idea. Store data in a global cache instead, so *all* users can access it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)" and "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Brad what if data is user-specific?

Answer (score 1):

If amount of retrieved data is not big, then yes - getting everything at once is a way to go. On the other hand if its hundreds of thousands of records then your current approach - server-side paging is a much better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad approach, because you are storing per user, which means that every logged in user that goes to this page will potentially have their own copy of all the data.

Do real custom paging, as opposed to built-in paging, which still gets the whole data set and then shows one page at a time, so if you need to show 10 records on one page, then you only ask your data store (i.e. database) for 10 records and nothing more. It is more chatty than one single call, but you will have more efficient use of memory and not having that first time loading lag of the entire data set.

Comment: The only drawback would be if SP call is really expensive (time-wise etc.)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - that is a possibility, but I would roll the dice on that problem versus the load everything approach. Maybe that is just me, though. :-)

Comment: If there a time issue retrieving 20 rows, then I would visit how one is retrieving the rows and refactor.

Comment: @KarlAnderson-Can you please give a bit detail on how to use your way.I am not very experienced in asp.net and have to deal with similar condiation.

Answer (score 0):

Just display the data in a Gridview, Set Datasource as a SQLdatasoure and on the Gridview properties set AllowPaging = "True" and PageSize = "20". This will do it. On SQLDatasoure set EnableCaching ="True" if you don't want requests made for every page.

Answer (score 0):

If money is not an issue, I strongly recommend you looking into either DevExpress or Telerik control suite along with an ORM tool that supports IQueryable.

DevExpress and Telerik grid control has paging feature out-of-box.  Binding the grid to IQueryable will sure help with performance.

Comment: `<personal_opinion>`ORM is evil.`</personal_opinion>`